# JBOSS deployment - Operation ("add") failed

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jboss7.x

I am trying to deploy a hello world web application in my local JBOSS.
here is my Index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=BIG5"
pageEncoding="BIG5"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=BIG5">
<title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Thank you for coming!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I have web.xml configured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>Index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

But when I run as server, I got following error:

```
12:48:51,568 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("configuration" => "handler"),
    ("file" => "welcome-content")
]) - failure description: "WFLYUT0095: the path ['C:\\JBOSS_7.1/welcome-content'] doesn't exist on file system"
12:48:51,576 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
12:48:51,578 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
12:48:51,618 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
12:48:51,647 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
12:48:51,757 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYPAT0050: JBoss EAP cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
12:48:51,777 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/NEWTMISDEV]
12:48:51,778 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
12:48:51,786 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\JBOSS_7.1\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
12:48:51,790 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\JBOSS_7.1\standalone\deployments
12:48:51,799 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "HelloWorld.jar" (runtime-name: "HelloWorld.jar")
12:48:52,076 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
12:48:52,129 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.9.Final-redhat-1 (Apache CXF 3.1.12.redhat-1) 
12:48:52,341 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final-redhat-1
12:48:52,556 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
12:48:52,601 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("host" => "default-host"),
    ("location" => "/")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["org.wildfly.extension.undertow.handler.welcome-content"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["org.wildfly.undertow.host.location.default-server.default-host./ is missing [org.wildfly.extension.undertow.handler.welcome-content]"]
}
12:48:52,626 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "HelloWorld.jar" (runtime-name : "HelloWorld.jar")
12:48:52,629 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service org.wildfly.extension.undertow.handler.welcome-content (missing) dependents: [service org.wildfly.undertow.host.location.default-server.default-host./]
```

I am new to JBOSS, I have no idea what does

Comment: Did you checked `"WFLYUT0095: the path ['C:\\JBOSS_7.1/welcome-content'] doesn't exist on file system"`

Comment: the error was gone after editing in your way, but I can still cannot access the index.jsp

Comment: it shows 404 - Not Found when I use url:http://127.0.0.1:8080/HelloWorld

Comment: Go the *standalone/deployments* folder and determine what is the status of your jar file.

Comment: I am not sure how to check the status of the jar file, but I restart the JBOSS, it shows an error 14:21:07,343 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0021: Deployment content C:\JBOSS_7.1\standalone\deployments\HelloWorld.jar appears to be incomplete and is not progressing toward completion. This content cannot be auto-deployed.

Comment: sorry, I think the error comes because I check "always publish to those servers" and "Auto-deploy to selected server after build" in Publish setting. However, I still cannot see the index.jsp